# Update knockout view after getting data from server

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I'm trying to utilise the demo here:

http://knockoutjs.com/examples/cartEditor.html

However, in the dataset used, which is: sampleProductCategories - it is static in the example.

I want to populate that dataset after calling an API via jQuery getJson.

So the markup will exist on the page - however it won't yet have the data to populate the view.

How to I retrigger the markup to redraw itself, when the sampleProductCategories list changes?

eg - can this part be redrawn/rebound to the data?

```
 <tbody data-bind='foreach: lines'>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select data-bind='options: sampleProductCategories, optionsText: "TypeName", optionsCaption: "Select...", value: TypeID'></select>
        </td>
        <td data-bind="with: category">
            <select data-bind='options: products, optionsText: "name", optionsCaption: "Select...", value: $parent.product'></select>
        </td>
```

Thank you,

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `observableArray` for your options and then populate them by an AJAX request.  The UI will update accordingly.

Here is an updated sample of the cart editor that uses an empty `observableArray` and updates it in a setTimeout after 1 second with the static data (like you would with an AJAX call).   http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/TmUDc/